# How to use Thevenin's theorem in a circuit with more than one source?

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin, homework

[image]

Attempts thus far at the solution:[image]

Comment: How did the 6V source magically appear at the bottom of your solution? Are you saying that you think that \$V_O\$ is 6V? You need to show a great deal more work than this...we are not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: Convert the 6 volt source and 6 kohm resistor to a current source. Ditto the -12 volts source and its resistor. Add current sources together. Merge the resistors by using parallel resistor method.... dead easy to find - 3 volts after converting back to a single voltage source. This is intended to be a hint. If you need much more help, maybe you should change your course?

Comment: Your adventures in the math site make surely some of us wonder how this can be a problem. The Thevenin equivalent voltage should be calculated obeying the whole circuit analysis theory, only having the Vo terminals open. No shortcuts should be used if they are not strictly based on proven theorems like voltage source to current source conversion. Jumping from math to electronics is no excuse to start slip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been over 24 hours now so does this help you move towards your solution: -

[image]

Can you now see why the answer is -3 volts?